# PHP Form-If Values are empty reload page, if not empty move to the form processing page

Tags: php, forms, validation

I want the values first_name, last_name, and email to be checked. If the values are empty then reload the page. I have error messages that display when the page is reloaded if those values are http://cdubach.com...., I believe my logic is correct but for some reason it is not working. I appreciate the assistance!

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="

<?php 

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {                                      
        if (empty($_POST["first_name"]) || empty($_POST["last_name"]) || empty($_POST["email"])) {
            echo "";
        } elseif (isset($_POST["first_name"]) && isset($_POST["last_name"]) && isset($_POST["email"])) {
           echo "http://cdubach.com/inc/send_form_email.php";
        }                                
    }

?>">
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the form has to have been submitted in order to check if those fields are empty. Are you expecting that users will submit the form with those fields not filled in?

Comment: Using this method, the user will have to submit the form twice. And before the second form submit, a value can be removed and the form can still be submitted. Instead you could save the values to `$_SESSION` and do a  `header('location: ....');`

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work if you inserted PHP code directly in the form's `action` tag:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="click" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    display();
} 

function display() {

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if (empty($_POST["first_name"]) || empty($_POST["last_name"]) || empty($_POST["email"])) {

        echo "";

    } else if  (isset($_POST["first_name"]) && isset($_POST["last_name"]) && isset($_POST["email"])) {

        echo "http://cdubach.com/inc/send_form_email.php";
    }

    else {

    }

}

}

?>
```

Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: Normally it's best practice to put the form processing logic **before** the form display, this allows redirects, message(s) to be set up / displayed, etc.

Comment: @CalebDuBach So, is this what you're looking for?